# Using wget in conjunction with an OpenID Login

Tags: linux, bash, shell, wget

I have a (legit) edge case where I would like to download a web page using any command line tool, but the web page needs an OpenID login to show the content I need.

`wget` supports [basic auth and FTP](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html), but I can't think of a sane way to use it in conjuction with an OpenID login. The only way I can think of

- Perform an OpenID login using `wget`
- Somehow store the resulting session cookie
- Try to fetch the page using another `wget` call, and `--load-cookies` the cookies from the last call

this seems complex to build, though, as IIRC the OpenID login process is not entirely as straightforward as your plain old web site login. Does anyone either

- know a less complex way (performing the OpenID login manually somewhere else would be completely acceptable)
- know a ready-made implementation of what I describe above? I'm keen on avoiding having to build this from scratch if at all possible.

Other inspirations are welcome as well.

I can work either on Linux or on Windows. Linux would be preferred from an infrastructure point of view but either platform is fine.

Comment: Will you consider switching tools? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462950/openid-via-curl

Comment: @anthony that looks interesting, thank you very much. I need what wget can do with `--page-requisites` - it tries to load and save all related images and style sheets. I'll investigate whether `curl` can do that, too. If it can, my problem is solved.

Comment: Ahh, too bad, curl can't do this. It can only fetch the page structure, but not retrieve the related resources.

Comment: damn! That's too bad. But you can see by that answer that your idea of multiple `wget` calls is on the right track.

Comment: @anthony yeah! I will be experimenting with this and add feedback here if I get anywhere.

Comment: nice. Let us know how you go.

Answer (score 2):

> performing the OpenID login manually somewhere else

Well the best I can think of is to use any browser for logging in to whatever service you want. The service will then preserve your "state" somehow in a cookie at your browser.

Get that cookie, e.g. store it at cookie.txt and pass it in the header

```
wget --header="Cookie: $(cat cookie.txt)" http://...
```

as long as the session is valid, you can use the wget script. Should work for 99% of all cases, thought probably not for online banking (if it does... switch banks immediately :-P)

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I used "document.cookie" in the JavaScript console to get the cookie string, saved it in `cookie.txt`, and then used your string as above - worked a charm.